# deleting form post that already in array

Tags: php

hello guys I have a form and I want to add a function in it ,
I have a list of texts stored in an array

```
$colors = array('red','blue','green');
```

and a form with a text input and submit .
I want for example when someone types some of the colors listed in the `$colors` array automaticly those texts get trimmed or get replaced with blank text . I don't know what is the real function to finish this so I'm asking for help right now . sorry for my bad english and thanks for your help brothers.

Comment: You should have a look to [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function, is it returns `true` you can replace the string with a blank text

Comment: give me the file code please

Comment: that's what I got in my mind: $post = $_POST['input']; if(in_array($post,$colors)) then what?

Comment: This is not what stackoverflow is supposed to be, show us what you tried and where you find problems so we can help out

Answer (score 0):

```
if( in_array($input, $colors)) {
    //get the key
    $key = array_search($input, $colors);
    $colors[$key] = "";//you can use unset($colors[$key]); if you want the entry gone!
}
```

That should solve the problem

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many ways to do this:

```
$searchString = ""; //User search here

$colors = array('red','blue','green');

foreach($colors as &$values){
    $pattern = "/". $values ."/";
    $searchString = preg_replace($pattern, "", $searchString);
}

//Remove any unnecessary spaces from the result
$searchString = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $searchString);

echo $searchString;
```